# ./configure: line 2178 config.log permission denied

Tags: linux

I want to install a library libevent . I forgot to `su root` and run `./configure` under my user acount `esolve`. Then I notice I there are errors after `make install` with `esolve`.

my `root` can't modify files which are modified by `esolve`(I'm not very clear why, because this computer linux OS is configured by some system/network administrator ).

now I `su root` and run `./configure`, and I got error:

```
 ./configure: line 2178 config.log permission denied
```

so where can I find the config.log file and remove or modify it?

FYI:
    my computer: 3.6.10-2.fc16.x86_64
    the directory, where the library installation folder is,  is mounted from another computer.

thanks!

Comment: this is impossible for us to know without more information.  For starters, what Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Avoid working as `root`**. If you screw up, you will have much more work to redo.

Instead, learn how to install software as a user.

If possible, always try to install software **from packages first**. Most likely, the packages will be a lot easier to use and install.

There are some reasons when `root` cannot modify software, for example when you are using a network file system. The remote host might not trust "root", and will map access to `nobody`, who then cannot modify the files created by `esolve`. If you try to work as much as regular user as possible, you won't run into such problems as easily.